# Does 听说你去丽江玩儿了 imply they are still in 丽江?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

From 标准教程HSK4上 (page 88):

> A:**听说你去丽江玩儿了**？那儿怎么样？
>   B:那里特别美，空气也很新鲜。

If I'm not mistaken, the 了 is the [change-of-state 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Change_of_state_with_%22le%22).  But this gives two possibilities:

1. The change of state is B going from B's former location to 丽江.
2. The change of state is B going from 丽江 to B's present location.

My impression is that since the 了 is not directly after 去 ([completion 了](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_completion_with_%22le%22)), we can deduce B is still in 丽江, and maybe A and B are talking on the phone.  However, 玩儿 is also a verb, so maybe 了 implies its completion (instead of 去).

**Question**: Does 听说你去丽江玩儿了 imply they are still in 丽江?

Comment: No. If they were still at 麗江, one would unambiguously say; 聽說你在麗江玩啊！

Comment: When you have complete actions in a row it is supposed that you put 了 on the last one. That's why it's after 玩儿 and not after 去.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A:听说你去丽江玩儿了？那儿怎么样？
>
> B:那里特别美，空气也很新鲜。

From the context, we can deduce that B is currently not in 丽江 because B replies **那里**特别美. If B is still there, he/she would say **这里**特别美.

However, 听说你去丽江玩儿了 could be interpreted either way you suggested. The sentence only tells you have gone to/arrived 丽江, but it doesn't tell you are currently out or not. Additional information must be required to determine whether you are still in 丽江 or not.

It's clear, in your context, B is already out of the town.

**PS**. It's also possible that B is still on the train to 丽江, when A is talking to B on the phone saying 听说你去丽江玩儿了. But this is not the case in OP's context.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. It depends. If you talk to the person face 2 face, then it is obvious that that person is not in 丽江

However, if you text to some one the same, you don't know whether that person is still in 丽江 or not. In this situation, it can mean either of it.

Answer (score 0):

> A:听说你去丽江玩儿了？那儿怎么样？
>   B:那里特别美，空气也很新鲜。

I delete 了

> A:听说你去丽江玩儿？那儿怎么样？
>   B:那里特别美，空气也很新鲜。

no meter B is come back, or still in 麗江 talking on the phone

two example is still all the same, you can't B's position in this conversation

了 here let you know, he already **"arrived"** 麗江